# Worldborder Question / Detect players

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering if you could have a player can go through a worldborder. You can do this by using a ender pearl, but we want it so you just can go through it, Like it's air. I have tried searching it but I haven't found anything.

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible in the current patch. You might be able to do some magic with putting players in spectator mode temporarily near the world border, but you'd also need to give them a resistance 5 buff, since players outside a world border take suffocation damage.

Comment: Please only ask one question per… well, question.

Comment: Just saying you've searched doesn't help.  Show us *something* that you've tried, and what it does, and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a player can't go through the world border (out from the inside at least). That's one of its features. You can however fly through in spectator mode.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need a player to go through the world border? The world border plugin is designed specifically to NOT allow passage through it. Not sure what version of WB your server is running but on ours running 1.8.7 (on Spigot 1.12.2) you cannot get through it in spectator mode nor with ender pearls. You have to have a bypass perm to go through the world border.  I don't know of any glitches/hacks that allow you to circumvent what WB is supposed to do.

Comment: Downvoted because I play-tested potential exploits on our server and let you know they don't work and there's no way that I know of to get around what the plugin is supposed to do?  Cool beans.